# Trying to remember a book I read in the late 60's

Tags: story-identification

Book was about all of Human History and everything humans did from the beginning of time was all to help an alien planet. Don't really have much more of a memory about the story only that I think it is a sci fi classic.

Comment: 2001: A Space Odyssey?

Comment: This is very broad and fits a variety of novels. You need to be more specific about the events. What kind of aliens? How did they help humanity? Why did they help? Etc etc

Comment: The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy?

Comment: @Chenmunka - too early, HHG was 70s, but good guess

Comment: If it was a short story, I'd say it was '[Does a bee care?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Does_a_Bee_Care%3F)', but if it's a full novel, the "Sirens of Titan" seems most likely.  Do details like Stonehenge and the Great Wall of China being messages from the alien's people sound familiar?

Comment: Another possibility is [*Triplanetary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplanetary_(novel)) by E.E. "Doc" Smith, first published as a serial in 1934 and made into a novel later. The Wikipedia plot summary says, *"The first [part] explains the series background, which consists of a conflict between the evil Eddorians and the benevolent Arisians. This conflict is carried out throughout the history of an oblivious humankind on Earth. The Arisians undertake a eugenics project to breed two human genetic lines that are intended to become the ultimate weapon in Arisia's cosmic war with Eddore."* >

Comment: <  *"The author takes five defining chapters to cover the background of the Kinnison line: the destruction of Atlantis in a nuclear war, an attempted coup in Rome against the Eddorian-controlled Nero, the First and Second World Wars, and, finally, a nuclear Third World War. In each of these periods he tells part of the story of the two families who will be of importance later on, and who will produce the two people whose children will be the culmination of the human breeding line, Kimball Kinnison and Clarissa MacDougall. One genetic line is surnamed "Kinnison" or some close variation."*

Answer (score 4):

*[The Sirens of Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sirens_of_Titan)* by Kurt Vonnegut, Jr. possibly, where human history and accomplishment is all to provide a message between  Tralfamadore and an alien crashed on earth.

> *The Sirens of Titan* largely deals with questions of free will, with multiple characters being stripped of it and the revelation that humanity had been secretly manipulated for millennia for an inane purpose playing major roles in the story.